# Warmup Neo4j database after spring initialization

Tags: java, spring, neo4j

I use a Neo4J database with nearly 500k nodes. When I startup my Spring application and do the first query, it takes about 4-5 seconds. This happens just for the first query, so I thought I could do a warmup after spring is initialized to make all subsequent queries faster.

This is my `applicationContext.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

    <!-- neo4j database -->
    <util:map id="config">
        <entry key="enable_remote_shell" value="false" />
    </util:map>

    <bean id="graphDbFactory" class="org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory" />

    <bean id="graphDbBuilder" factory-bean="graphDbFactory"
        factory-method="newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder">
        <constructor-arg value="/path/to/db" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="graphDbBuilderFinal" factory-bean="graphDbBuilder"
        factory-method="setConfig">
        <constructor-arg ref="config" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="graphDatabaseService" factory-bean="graphDbBuilderFinal"
        factory-method="newGraphDatabase" destroy-method="shutdown" class="org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.app.components" />
</beans>
```

I saw that one way to wait for Spring beans initialization was to implement an `ApplicationListener`, and the regular way to warmup the database with Neo was to call the `apoc.runtime.warmup()` function, so I did as follows:

```
package com.app.components;

@Component
public class StartupTasks implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(StartupTasks.class);

    @Autowired
    GraphDatabaseService db;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        executeTestSelect();
    }

    private void executeTestSelect() {
        LOG.info("Warming up Neo4j...");

        Transaction tx = db.beginTx();
        db.execute("CALL apoc.warmup.run()");
        tx.close();

        LOG.info("Warmup complete.");
    }
}
```

This one didn't work, everything gets correctly logged but the first neo4j query is still slow.

Since this approach didn't work, I edited the `executeTestSelect` method to run a real query and process the results like this:

```
private void executeTestSelect() {
    String textToSearch = "a"; // returns almost all nodes, should make neo4j cache them all
    Transaction tx = db.beginTx();
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put("textToSearch", textToSearch );
    Result resultSet = db.execute("MATCH (n:PROD) WHERE n.description CONTAINS {textToSearch} RETURN n",
                params);
    Iterator<Node> results = resultSet.columnAs("n");
    int count = 0;
    while (results.hasNext()) {
        results.next();
        count++:
    }
    tx.close();
    LOG.info("Neo4j cache done. Processed " + count + " nodes.");
}
```

This time the startup takes 4-5 seconds just to execute the query, but then it prints

> Neo4j cache done. Processed 0 nodes.

This is weird, because the exact same query run when the app is fully initialized returns 450k nodes.

What am I missing? Is it possible that when reaching `onApplicationEvent` the Neo4j DB hasn't been initialized yet and can't execute queries?

How do I correctly warmup a neo4j database right after the complete spring app initialization?

Comment: I didn't test this: it may work if you replace `ContextRefreshedEvent` with `ContextStartedEvent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I discovered this by pure luck.

I removed the `ApplicationListener` and created a `@Service` class with the `@Autowired` annotation on the method that does the warmup, it seems to be working.

I discovered this by removing a class field without seeing the `@Autowired` annotation left here, and it worked. I tried it several times, the warmup is working now. I don't know if it is documented somewhere in the Spring Documentation.

This is my final class:

```
package com.app.components;

@Component
public class Neo4jWarmup {

    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(StartupTasks.class);

    @Autowired
    GraphDatabaseService db;

    /*
     * this did the trick - the method gets called 
     * after Spring initialization and the DB works as expected
     */
    @Autowired 
    public void neo4jWarmup() {
        executeTestSelect();
    }

    private void executeTestSelect() {
        LOG.info("Warming up Neo4j...");

        Transaction tx = db.beginTx();
        db.execute("CALL apoc.warmup.run()");
        tx.close();

        LOG.info("Warmup complete.");
    }
}
```